# how to make a service, SOAP web service in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, soap

Please forgive me for this basic and a little theoretical question as I dont know much about web services.

I m not refering WCF service, I am reffering simple service in .net / C#. I want to know how to know is it soap or rest service ?

How we can change this type from Soap to Rest and vice versa ?

Thanks

Comment: WCF is the replacement for ASMX services. You should not use ASMX for new development, as it is a legacy technology. BTW, WCF produces SOAP services, including simple ones.

Comment: The terminology from your question is confusing. By saying it is not WCF assumes it is ASMX (classic XML Web Services). If it truly is RESTful then it likely is still WCF based. A clarification will need to be made in order to know whether my answer is appropriate.

Comment: http://servicestack.net/

Comment: If you are bound to HTTP, if you can just wait for Web API / MVC 4, don't start anything new with WCF ;-) (servicestack is also a good suggestion though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML Web Services (aka classic/legacy ASMX web services) should *not* be used for active development. If you must, there is [a nice walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx) for adding Web references in more recent versions of Visual Studio (> 2005).

On the other hand, if your web service is truly Restful then you won't be able to create the equivalent of a service reference to it. You'll need to either use the `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, or the new `HttpClient` from .NET 4.5 (also available from the Rest starter kit which is depreciated as well).

---

As an alternative if you are looking to implement a client that is able to handle both situations, I would recommend `HttpWebRequest` to *POST* to the SOAP (non-WCF) service. The problem with this method is you'll likely have to wrap the request in the SOAP wrapper yourself. Luckily there are [examples](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2007/03/01/writing-soap-request-from-scratch/) of doing so on the net that you can at least use as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

ASMX services are build upon SOAP. REST is simply a HTTP based, You can access(or call) your business resources the way you access the normal URLs.

For ex in products catalog system, by using asmx you create set of functions to add,update,delete products. like addProduct(),updateProduct, etc..

But in REST, you will be having single point of access, like http:\mysystem\prodcuts. To retrieve,add,update,delete products, you will be using respective HTTP verbs (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) on the same URL.

so,technically it's not possible to convert asmx(SOAP) service to rest...